# Deleting specified number of rows from SQLite database

Tags: android, sqlite

I am trying to remove 6 rows from the database using the following statement but I get the error shown below.

```
getWritableDatabase().execSQL("DELETE FROM tblname ORDER BY _id ASC LIMIT 6;");
```

Error:

> Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "ORDER": syntax error: DELETE FROM tblname*

I tried reformatting the SQL in different ways but couldn't get it to work. What am I missing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
DELETE FROM tblname WHERE `_id` IN (SELECT `_id` FROM tblname ORDER BY `_id` ASC LIMIT 6)
```

I think your problem may have been quoting the `_id`, though.

Comment: Thank you. That exact SQL worked. I am not really sure why the original SQL didn't work though. According to this documentation (for use of LIMIT in DELETE) it should've worked

http://www.sqlite.org/lang_delete.html

Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 5):

The LIMIT and ORDER options for DELETE in sqlite are optional, and it appears they aren't enabled on Android. Borealid's SQL above will work fine even without the quotes.