# Android Sqlite: Use of delete with LIMIT and OFFSET

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I want to delete a limited number of rows with offset, but I only managed to delete the entire table.

I tried the following methods:

```
1. DELETE FROM tblname ORDER BY _id LIMIT N OFFSET M
2. DELETE FROM tblname WHERE `_id` IN (SELECT `_id` FROM tblname ORDER BY `_id` ASC LIMIT ? OFFSET ?)
```

The first statement gives a known error: `Error: Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "ORDER": syntax error: DELETE FROM tblname`

[The second statement wipes the entire table.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3436801/deleting-specified-number-of-rows-from-sqlite-database/3436809#3436809)

What am I doing wrong? What is a good alternative?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

SQLite support for ORDER and LIMIT in DELETE statements is optional and may not be built into the library you're using. See http://www.sqlite.org/lang_delete.html

Comment: `What about:  String deleteWithOffset = "DELETE FROM 'tableName' WHERE '_id' IN (SELECT '_id' FROM 'tableName' ORDER BY '_id' ASC LIMIT ? OFFSET ?)"; db.execSQL(deleteWithOffset, new String[] {String.valueOf(numberOfLocations), String.valueOf(firstLocationOffset)});`